# How to include Greek/plotmath characters for one label in legend for ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code, with three types of AR levels, and four Diets. I set up the following plot:

```
require(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
ChickWt <- data.frame(ChickWeight, AR = sample(c("p=0", "p=1", "hat(p)"), size = 578, replace = T))

p1 <- ggplot(ChickWt, aes(x=Time, y=weight,
colour=Diet, Group = Chick, linetype = AR)) + geom_line()
p1
```

which yields:

[image]

What I would like to have happen is to replace the hat(p) in the legend with the mathematical symbol \hat on top of p. How do I do thsi in the legend?

Thank you very much for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to succeed:

```
exprvec <- expression( hat(p), p==0, p==1)
p1  + scale_linetype_manual(values=1:4, labels = exprvec)
```

If shifting the labels, so that hat(p) is centered, you could use `phantom`, ... or perhaps use `guide_legend`, although the help page does not describe a "centered" option for `label.position`, and I couldn't get it to accept a `label.hjust` argument.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! How do I make the legends go to two separate columns, one for AR and one for Diet? I tried adding: + guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=2)) to no effect, perhaps because these are two separate legends?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. There are two separate columns. Is the desire for them to be side by side? The default is for there to be one legend box but you could move it into the upper-left-hand region where it would not interfere with the lines using: `+ theme(legend.position=c(0.1,0.75))` and they now appear "separate" on the basis of the background.